# Get counters within cycles

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list as follows:

```
list_sequences = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1]
```

I want to create another list with the count of the occurrences, but the occurrence of 2 and 3 is reset after an occurrence of 1.

Something like:

```
occurrence_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

is there a simple pythonic way to do so?

Comment: Please update your question with the complex unpythonic code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` to keep account of what is going on:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

list_sequences = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1]

def make_occurrence(seq):
    counter = defaultdict(int)
    occurrence = []
    for item in seq:
        count = counter[item] + 1
        if item  == 1:
            counter.clear()
        counter[item] = count
        occurrence.append(count)
    return occurrence


print(make_occurrence(list_sequences))
```

Output as requested

Comment: this is really neat, I was trying to get the difference of shift and count, but got really messy